# How do I get the dom element which has not rendered with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a simple `js` code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.querySelector('#nav-toggle')); // this will get null
        console.log($('#nav-toggle')); // this will get the element
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#">link</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.querySelector('#nav-toggle')); // this will get the element
        console.log($('#nav-toggle')); // this will get the element
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I comment, the first `document.querySelector('#nav-toggle')` will get `null`, I guess the problem is the `dom element` has not been rendered, because the second get the element.

But `jQuery` can get the element regardless of the place, How could `jQuery` do this?

Comment: Add the code in the head section to a document.ready function.

Comment: You spelled toggle wrong in the query

Comment: Javascript and jQuery can only get an element once it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're many different ways to check if things are fully loaded. Which way to go should always be based on your need. You don't want to wait longer than what's really necessary.

Just to clarify, the "window.load" is **not** identical with jQuery's "$(document).ready()".

If you want a "vanilla" alternative, DOMContentLoaded is your rescue.

**DOMContentLoaded**

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
});
```

**window.load**

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.onload = function() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misinformed. Jquery can not get an element that is not yet there. What you can do with jQuery is that use its [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method, which is run after the document is loaded. You can get similar results with vanilla javascript using [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following and you will always find the element if it is present in the DOM

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
          console.log(document.querySelector('#nav-toggle')); // this will get null
          console.log($('#nav-togglle')); // this will get the element
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#">link</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.querySelector('#nav-toggle')); // this will get the element
        console.log($('#nav-togglle')); // this will get the element
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to explain, jQuery wasn't doing any magic there. For the purpose of testing, you can swap your vanilla javascript and jquery code lines, try a few times by refreshing your page, you might get to see different results.

In your currect scenario, it is just that jQuery could find that element because the element had been loaded before the jQuery statement was called (Asynchronous nature, you see!)